# How to update Parent RecyclerView's components from child RecyclerView's components in android Studio using java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, parent-child

As you can see in the picture I have two recycler Views (Parent and nested Recycler View), the parent recycler View is showing Semesters' list while the nested recycler View is showing subjects' list for that particular Semester. Now the problem is that I want to update the SGPA TextView (0.00) next to Semester TextView when a user enters credit hours and letter grade in particular Semester's subjects' list ... I am doing it by the following provided code, but it does not satisfy my needs...

[image: 1]

**Child Model Class**

```
public class ChildModelClass {

    String subject_LBL;
    String credit_hours;
    String letter_grade;
    int delete_icon;

    public ChildModelClass(String subject_LBL, int delete_icon, String credit_hours, String letter_grade) {
        this.subject_LBL = subject_LBL;
        this.delete_icon = delete_icon;
        this.credit_hours = credit_hours;
        this.letter_grade = letter_grade;
    }

    public String getSubject_LBL() {
        return subject_LBL;
    }

    public String getCredit_hours() {
        return credit_hours;
    }

    public void setCredit_hours(String credit_hours) {
        this.credit_hours = credit_hours;
    }

    public String getLetter_grade() {
        return letter_grade;
    }

    public void setLetter_grade(String letter_grade) {
        this.letter_grade = letter_grade;
    }

    public void setSubject_LBL(String subject_LBL) {
        this.subject_LBL = subject_LBL;
    }

    public int getDelete_icon() {
        return delete_icon;
    }

    public void setDelete_icon(int delete_icon) {
        this.delete_icon = delete_icon;
    }

}
```

**Child Adapter Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> childModelClassList;
    ArrayList<String> credit_hour_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//    ArrayList<String> letter_grade_arrayList;
    boolean isOnTextChanged = false;
    int total_credit_hours = 0;
    Context context;
    TextView sGPA_value;
    View rootView;

    public ChildAdapter(ArrayList<ChildModelClass> childModelClassList,Context context) {
        this.childModelClassList = childModelClassList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChildAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_rv_layout,parent,false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        rootView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        sGPA_value = rootView.findViewById(R.id.semester_gpa_value);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChildAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ChildModelClass list = childModelClassList.get(position);
        holder.TIET_credit_hour.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                isOnTextChanged = true;
                // list.credit_hours = charSequence.toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                total_credit_hours = 0;
                if (isOnTextChanged) {
                    isOnTextChanged = false;

                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i <= holder.getAdapterPosition(); i++) {
                            if (i != holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
                                credit_hour_arrayList.add("0");
                            }else {
                                credit_hour_arrayList.add("0");
                                credit_hour_arrayList.set(holder.getAdapterPosition(),editable.toString());

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i <= credit_hour_arrayList.size() -1; i++) {
                            int tempTotalCreditHours = Integer.parseInt(credit_hour_arrayList.get(i));
                            total_credit_hours = total_credit_hours + tempTotalCreditHours;
                        }
//                        total_final_credit_hours = String.valueOf(total_credit_hours);
                        sGPA_value.setText(String.valueOf(total_credit_hours));
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        total_credit_hours = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= holder.getAdapterPosition(); i++) {
                            int newPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                            if (i == newPosition) {
                                credit_hour_arrayList.set(newPosition,"0");
                            }
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < credit_hour_arrayList.size()-1; i++) {
                            int tempTotalCreditHours = Integer.parseInt(credit_hour_arrayList.get(i));
                            total_credit_hours = total_credit_hours + tempTotalCreditHours;
                        }
//                        total_final_credit_hours = String.valueOf(total_credit_hours);
                        sGPA_value.setText(String.valueOf(total_credit_hours));
                    }

                }

            }
        });

        holder.subject_LBL.setText(list.getSubject_LBL());
        holder.delete_icon.setImageResource(list.getDelete_icon());
        holder.TIET_credit_hour.setText(list.getCredit_hours());
        holder.TIET_letter_grade.setText(list.getLetter_grade());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return childModelClassList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ConstraintLayout child_rv_layout, card_view_layout;
        MaterialCardView card_view;
        TextView subject_LBL;
        ImageView delete_icon;
        TextInputLayout TIL_credit_hour, TIL_letter_grade;
        TextInputEditText TIET_credit_hour, TIET_letter_grade;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            child_rv_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_rv_layout);
            card_view_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_layout);

            card_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

            subject_LBL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_LBL);

            delete_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_icon);

            TIL_credit_hour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIL_credit_hour);
            TIL_letter_grade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIL_letter_grade);

            TIET_credit_hour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIET_credit_hour);
            TIET_letter_grade = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIET_letter_grade);

            delete_icon.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                childModelClassList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent Model Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ParentModelClass {

    String semester_LBL;
    String semester_GPA_value;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> childModelClassList;

    public ParentModelClass(String semester_LBL, String semester_GPA_value, ArrayList<ChildModelClass> childModelClassList) {
        this.semester_LBL = semester_LBL;
        this.semester_GPA_value = semester_GPA_value;
        this.childModelClassList = childModelClassList;
    }

    public String getSemester_LBL() {
        return semester_LBL;
    }

    public void setSemester_LBL(String semester_LBL) {
        this.semester_LBL = semester_LBL;
    }

    public String getSemester_GPA_value() {
        return semester_GPA_value;
    }

    public void setSemester_GPA_value(String semester_GPA_value) {
        this.semester_GPA_value = semester_GPA_value;
    }
}
```

**Parent Adapter Class**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ParentAdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapterClass.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ParentModelClass> parentModelClassArrayList;
    Context context;

    public ParentAdapterClass(ArrayList<ParentModelClass> parentModelClassArrayList, Context context) {
        this.parentModelClassArrayList = parentModelClassArrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ParentAdapterClass.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_rv_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParentAdapterClass.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ParentModelClass list = parentModelClassArrayList.get(position);

        holder.semester_LBL.setText(list.getSemester_LBL());
        holder.semester_gpa_value.setText(list.getSemester_GPA_value());

        ChildAdapter childAdapter;
        childAdapter = new ChildAdapter(parentModelClassArrayList.get(position).childModelClassList, context);
        ListDecorator listDecorator = new ListDecorator(0,15,15,0);
        holder.child_rv.addItemDecoration(listDecorator);
        holder.child_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.child_rv.setAdapter(childAdapter);
        holder.child_rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        childAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parentModelClassArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ConstraintLayout parent_rv_layout, semester_gpa_display_layout;
        RecyclerView child_rv;
        TextView semester_LBL, semester_gpa_value;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            parent_rv_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_rv_layout);
            semester_gpa_display_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester_gpa_display_layout);

            child_rv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_rv);

            semester_LBL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester_LBL);
            semester_gpa_value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester_gpa_value);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout parent_layout, CGPA_display_layout;
    TextView Label_CGPA, CGPA_value;
    RecyclerView parent_rv;

    ArrayList<ParentModelClass> parentModelClassArrayList;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> childModelClassArrayList;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> semester_1;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> semester_2;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> semester_3;
    ArrayList<ChildModelClass> semester_4;


    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parent_layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        CGPA_display_layout = findViewById(R.id.CGPA_display_layout);
        Label_CGPA = findViewById(R.id.Label_CGPA);
        CGPA_value = findViewById(R.id.CGPA_value);
        parent_rv = findViewById(R.id.parent_rv);

        childModelClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        semester_1 = new ArrayList<>();
        semester_2 = new ArrayList<>();
        semester_3 = new ArrayList<>();
        semester_4 = new ArrayList<>();
        parentModelClassArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ParentAdapterClass parentAdapterClass;

        semester_1.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 1", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_1.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 2", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_1.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 3", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_1.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 4", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));

        semester_2.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 1", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_2.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 2", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_2.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 3", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_2.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 4", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));

        semester_3.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 1", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_3.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 2", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_3.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 3", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_3.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 4", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));

        semester_4.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 1", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_4.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 2", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_4.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 3", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));
        semester_4.add(new ChildModelClass("Subject 4", R.drawable.ic_delete, "", ""));

        parentModelClassArrayList.add(new ParentModelClass("Semester 1", "0.00", semester_1));
        parentModelClassArrayList.add(new ParentModelClass("Semester 2", "0.00", semester_2));
        parentModelClassArrayList.add(new ParentModelClass("Semester 3", "0.00", semester_3));
        parentModelClassArrayList.add(new ParentModelClass("Semester 4", "0.00", semester_4));


        parentAdapterClass = new ParentAdapterClass(parentModelClassArrayList,MainActivity.this);
        ListDecorator listDecorator = new ListDecorator(20, 0,0, 20);
        parent_rv.addItemDecoration(listDecorator);
        parent_rv.setAdapter(parentAdapterClass);
        parent_rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        parent_rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        parentAdapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to update the `parent` `textView` adapter from `child` `adapter`.

You are using this line of code:

```
rootView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

to be able to access `textview` (`semester_gpa_value`) from the child adapter.

There is a better way to achieve this using the `Observer pattern`, just send the text from the child adapter to the parent adapter. this way you will be able to update `semester_gpa_value` from parent adapter, so you don't need to access it in child adapter.

So make these changes in the child adapter:

```
public class ChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ChildViewHolder> {
    
    //...

    public interface ValueChangeListener {
        void onValueChange(String newValue);
    }

    private ValueChangeListener valueChangeListener;

    //...
    class ChildViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText TIET_credit_hour;

        public ChildViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //...
            TIET_credit_hour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TIET_credit_hour);

            TIET_credit_hour.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (valueChangeListener != null) {
                        // In this case, I just send the text as is to the parent adapter, but you can do whatever calculations you want before sending it.
                        valueChangeListener.onValueChange(s.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // this method must be called by parent adapter to listen for text change
    public void setValueChangeListener(ValueChangeListener valueChangeListener) {
        this.valueChangeListener = valueChangeListener;
    }
}
```

In your parent adapter, just call `childAdapter.setValueChangeListener(yourText)` to be able to receive the text sent by the child adapter:

ParentAdapter.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //...

        childAdapter.setValueChangeListener(new ChildAdapter.ValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(String newValue) {
                //Also here you can do any calculation you want before updating the text view. In this example I just show the text received from the child adapter.
                holder.semester_gpa_value.setText(newValue);
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, we are updating the text view of the parent adapter with the text received from the child adapter.